# RA position: accidentally submitted incomplete documents

Tags: application, application-cover-letter

I am coming to the end of a PhD, and recently submitted an application for an RA position at another university. For the application I had to submit a CV and cover letter.

Today I found out that my application was unsuccessful. However, after examining the documents that I submitted, I realised that I actually submitted a very early, incomplete draft of the cover letter (less than 100 words) and not the final version. This is completely my fault, an error on my part. The CV was the correct version.

Is there anything that I can do in this situation? I feel that the job role fitted my skills very well, almost a continuation of my PhD, so the correct cover letter could have made a difference. I am considering sending an email to explain the situation with the correct cover letter attached. However, the deadline for applications is closed, and I feel like the fact that I submitted the wrong document to begin with has reflected very badly on me, so probably won't make a difference.

Comment: Something is not clear to me: Is just the deadline closed (so all applications are under consideration) or they already made a decision and hired an RA?

Comment: @PsySp: The deadline for applications only closed last week, so I imagine that they are still considering applications and that there will be an interview process

Comment: @ΕngStan. Ok, I was confused by the sentence "Today I found out that my application was unsuccessful." Did you receive any notification message about the unsuccessful outcome of your application? At this point, I think it does not harm to send an explanatory mail with your situation. Mistakes can happen. In any case, doing so won't make a _negative_ difference.

Comment: "RA position?"  Can you clarify?  I usually take "RA" to mean research assistantship, a position normally occupied by a PhD student.